# Can CiviDiscount be used on a Contribution Page without Membership

Tags: contribution-page, cividiscount

I have seen references to CiviDiscount on contribution pages for memberships.  Can it be used for a fundraising dinner?  Note - I often struggle between creating an event or contribution page for fundraising dinners - both have tradeoffs

Comment: What is the downside of an Event in this scenario?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an extension that adds support for discounts on contributions:

https://civicrm.org/extensions/discount-contributions

Edit: It has been improved with time, and seems to be working well so far. In the long term, it might be more interesting to get it merged in the main CiviDiscount extension.

Comment: I've used this successfully out of the box, and another CiviCRM vendor submitted patches, so folks can consider this extension tested now.

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I want, but I don't seem to be able to install it. I've put the code in the extensions directory but it doesn't show up in the extentions screen for me to install (document says install as a regular extension). I do already have CiviDiscount installed.

Comment: Had to clear the CiviCRM cache to get it to install, but otherwise does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Discount for event registrations too, assuming you mean the fundraising dinner is an event sign up?

Comment: No, the point is that it is a contribution page.  not an event.

Comment: Ok, so I'm not sure thats the desired behaviour of CiviDiscount, Contribution pages without Membership are in effect donation pages so giving a discount on a donation doesn't seem to make sense. You could simply point supporters to a different donation page which implied the discount or something along those lines with a module.

Comment: I've had to work around this limitation at times, since I sometimes have a plain contribution page to buy a book or a t-shirt, with a member/code discount. In one case I duplicated/adapted the buildAmount function of cividiscount, and in one case I had to override the DiscountCalculator() because I didn't want to have to configure every single priceset-item.

Comment: @bgm can you share how you modified buildAmount function for applying discounts to a plain contribution page? I see it checks for page type but it gets confusing from there.

Comment: @schatz OK, posted below as an answer.

Comment: Just to add a use case where a contribution page is being used in a non membership/event setting and not a donation, we use for payment of assessment fees