# Page that uses CiviDiscount-- not events or memberships

Tags: civievent, contribution-page, cividiscount

I understand from [this thread](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7401/can-cividiscount-be-used-on-a-contribution-page-without-membership) that cividiscount is generally used for membership costs or event fees. For our events, we currently use a contribution page to collect fees so that we can use a price set and allow people to pay for more than one event at a time. Is there any kind of page I can set up to allow the use of CiviDiscounts as well as price-sets?

Comment: Some ideas that have been floated include: use a membership page somehow without conferring a meaningful membership, use a non-civ page that is somehow hooked into the civi price sets, change something so that contribution pages can have discounts. If you have ideas as to how to make any of these happen, please share!