# How do Cividiscount codes work when used with a price set?

Tags: cividiscount, discounts

I may be missing something obvious here, but...

I create a contribution page that makes use of a price set. The price set includes  a number of radio button price options.
I create discount code that provides a discount against one of these price options.
When I view the live contribution page, there is no field displayed where I can enter my discount code.
I can recreate this on the demo site at http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I view the live contribution page, there is no field displayed where I can enter my discount code.

Make sure the contribution page uses the Membership section. There is no discount functionality for *only* Donation pages as far as I can see from the [usage section](https://civicrm.org/extensions/cividiscount).

Also see [Can CiviDiscount be used on a Contribution Page without Membership](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7401/can-cividiscount-be-used-on-a-contribution-page-without-membership/7428)

Comment: Well I did say it was likely I'd missed something obvious...