# Installing extension to allow CiviDiscount without event or membership

Tags: extension, cividiscount

I want to use CiviDiscount for a contribution that is not an event or membership. I've tried with a priceset and that doesn't work. Looking at [Can CiviDiscount be used on a Contribution Page without Membership](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7401/can-cividiscount-be-used-on-a-contribution-page-without-membership/7428) I see this wasn't desogned to workbut @bgm has written some code that does this. Its an extension and I have put the code in the extension folder but it doesn't show on the system > extensions screen so I can't Enable it. Its described as a proof-of-concept extension so maybe I need to do something else. I do have CiviDiscount enabled. Not sure what to try next.

Extension is https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/discountcontributions

Answer (score 1):

Clear your CiviCRM cache or Hit the refresh button in extension page